ODBC connection to local Db2 database on Windows 10 fails with message "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
64 and 32 bit ODBC connections are defined, tested in ODBC manager of Windows.
It fails using other software with "DIAG [IM002] [Microsoft]" message (the Database and user are the same).
The connection string:
'Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DBALIAS=SAMPLE;Uid=<user>;Pwd=<pw>;'.
I have tried some variants; e.g. Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1} changed the message to DIAG [IM002] [Microsoft] Data source name is too long.
I Checked some elements in the registry, but failed to find the root of the problem.
Could you help me?  Thank you.

@bjoster First of all thank you.
All versions were "latest" some days ago at implementation. Trial with LibreOffice and BDS Prolog (32 and 64 bits versions) ended with common error. I copied the names from ODBC manager, where connection were successful (to SAMPLE database). I got the form of the connection string from the proposed link.
I start to ask community; if no result, I have to ask IBM.

Did you already fix this?  If not, your question should detail exactly how you are trying to connect from exactly which application. The connection-String needs to include DATABASE=sample;HOSTNAMe=localhost;PORT=...;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=...;PWD=...;` and if you specify the DRIVER, then it must match exactly the name shown in the odbcad32 for the matching bitness.

First of all, the problem still exists (trials for solution run parallel with other duties). My original installation introduced new users and planned DB-only check for rights. Next I have deleted and reinstalled the whole Db2 system (Db2 Server Edition v11.5.9000) with the existing system administrator as DB administrator, allowing external check for rights. In the list of selected features there is ODBC data sourse support and ODBC support. In the list of Installation specific driver details there is IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI name: IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1.

Solved problems:

Installation log ends with "MSI (c) ... Installation operation completed successfully", but there are known problems described at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/registration-ole-regsvr32-command-db2olefndll-fails-when-silently-installing-db2-without-creating-instance
For command db2 CATALOG SYSTEM ODBC DATA SOURCE  definition in ODBC Data Sources manager is not enough. But if there is a database with  identical to given to data source in Data Sources manager, then one may catalog it. Cataloging is not enough to avoid Data source name not found message.



Did you install the exact version needed? IBM sometimes misses beeing backwards compatible
Try to use your "new" ODBC connection with another database client (like Excel)
Triple check the data source name AND the driver name ("IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER"). The name does have to match exactly
Test your username/pwd agains the ODBC datasource
DBALIAS is the alias for your (DB2) database, not the Alias fpr your datasource (documentation: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2/)

If this does not help, contact software vendor.

Heureka! I browsed several IBM documents with description of connection strings of different circumstances and I found keyword DSN=<data source name> (as possible replacement of keyword DATABASE=<database name>) and it worked.
The successful connection string is:
Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DSN=name;Uid=user;Pwd=pwd;

